# How to make docker processes how volume, container and other folders not be created with root permissions

Tags: linux, docker, unix

Good evening, I have a problem that is giving me a lot of headaches in docker, basically it is that docker lifts all processes with root, and in my company they are limited with respect to root permissions, in this case there is some way to get containers , and everything related to it (volumes, container, etc) get up with my current user, and not with root?

Try using the solution of UID = $ {UID} GID = $ {GID}, but nothing, I still can't see the logs of my containers because it only has root access and the group root:

[image]

My docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:

  findAccountNumber:
    image: find-account-number
    container_name: find-account-number
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./MS-CuentaPagadora
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8081"
    ports:
      - 37005:8081
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"

  findAccountValidators:
    image: find-account-validators
    container_name: find-account-validators
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./MS-DigitosValidadores
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8082"
    ports:
      - 37006:8082
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"

  findComplementaryAccountInfo:
    image: find-complementary-account-info
    container_name: find-complementary-account-info
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./MS-ConsultaCuentaPagadoraPospago
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8083"
    ports:
      - 37007:8083
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
```

And the commands used to build and put the containers on top are:

```
UID=${UID} GID=${GID} docker-compose build
UID=${UID} GID=${GID} docker-compose up -d
```

[image]

My /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{

        "data-root": "/opt/docker",
        "storage-driver": "overlay2",
        "log-driver": "json-file",
        "log-opts": {
                "max-size": "10m",
                "max-file": "3"
  }
}
```

What can I do to change this?